# Array Index out of range when adding row to NSTableView

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I'm trying to create a coin flip simulation that will log the results of every coin flip in a NSTableView. However, when I go to insert a new row containing the result of the coin flip, I get a `Fatal error: Array index out of range` despite the index it's trying to insert to being 0. Here is part of my view controller class:

```
class CoinController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var shownImage: NSImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shownText: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var coinSelected: NSPopUpButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    @objc dynamic var values: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func flipCoin(_ sender: Any) {
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn

        let rand = Bool.random()
        let currentCoin = coinSelected.titleOfSelectedItem ?? ""
        if rand == true {
            self.shownImage.image = NSImage(named:currentCoin+"Heads")
            values.append("Heads")
        } else {
            self.shownImage.image = NSImage(named:currentCoin+"Tails")
            values.append("Tails")
        }
        self.shownImage.layer?.add(transition, forKey: "transition")

        let last = values.count-1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [last], withAnimation: .slideDown)
        tableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: [last], columnIndexes: IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<1))
        tableView.scrollRowToVisible(last)
        tableView.selectRowIndexes([last], byExtendingSelection: false)
    }
```

And here are my bindings:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are using array controller why do you insert the row *manually*? And why do you call `reloadData` right after `insertRows`? And be aware that `last` is not the last index anymore after inserting the row.

Comment: @vadian I'm new to swift and cocoa, and I haven't found any updated guides on TableViews relevant to what I'm aiming for, so I don't have a good grasp on Array Controllers and their uses relative to bindings. How should I go about inserting the row instead?

Comment: Just don't call any insert/delete/reload method. The array controller manages updating the UI when the data source array is modified.

Comment: Ah, I deleted those lines and it worked, TIL. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @vadian is `insertRows` allowed to add an animation?

Comment: @Willeke Yes but not together with `NSArrayController` bound to the data source array.